# Django models and managers circular import error

Tags: django, django-models

so In my project I have two directories:
`managers` and `models`.
here's my code: how I've imported objects around.
I also use objects as *typehints*, for example:

```py
@classmethod
    def get_overwrite_objects(cls, parent_object: DataSheetsCluster):
        return parent_object.roles
```

**models/roles.py**

```py
from api_backend.managers import RolesManager


class Role(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a Global-Role object.
    Roles have their own:
        - Hex Color Code [Integer Representation]
        - Name [&]
        - Position
        - Permissions.
    """
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-position']
        unique_together = ('position', 'parent',)

    objects = RolesManager()
```

**models/data_sheets.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django import dispatch
from api_backend.managers import (FieldDataManager, RolesManager)
...

class FieldData(models.Model):
    """
    A model which stores FieldData referencing it's parent.
    the data is JSON.stringified before insertion and is JSON.parsed
    upon retrieval.
    The record's size is stored as a float value in order to control the parent's size.
    """
    objects = FieldDataManager()
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    ...

class DataSheetsCluster(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a group of datasheets made by the owner.
    Has it's own icon, name and description.
    A parent can only have one owner at a time.
    """

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ('READ_DATA', 'can read cluster data'),
            ('WRITE_DATA', 'can write to cluster'),
            ('MANAGE_CLUSTER', 'can manage cluster'),
            ('MANAGE_FIELD_DATA', "can manage cluster's field data"),
            ('MANAGE_DATASHEETS', "can manage cluster's datasheets"),
            ('MANAGE_ROLES', "can manage cluster's roles"),
            ('MANAGE_FIELDS', "can manage cluster's fields"),
            ('MANAGE_CONSTRAINTS', "can manage cluster's constraints")
        ]

    objects = models.Manager()
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, db_index=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('api_backend.Member')
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('api_backend.Role')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('api_backend.DataSheetsCategory')
    datasheets = models.ManyToManyField(DataSheet)
    total_size_limit = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, db_index=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [name]


@dispatch.receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=DataSheetsCluster)
def set_default_cluster(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Assigns default features for the given cluster.
    These features include:
        - the default role for the cluster [@everyone].
        - the default datasheets and categories for the cluster.
    """
    if created:
        roles_manager = RolesManager()
        roles_manager.create_default_roles(instance)
```

**managers/positions.py**

```py
from django.db import (models, transaction)
from api_backend.models import (Role, DataSheetsCluster, DataSheet, DataSheetField, DataSheetsCategory)
...

class RolesPositionManager(PositionalManager):
    """
    A positional manager for role-objects.
    Roles have an unique position- attribute, which requires
    rotating and overwriting during updates.

    Roles also have an is_default attribute, which
    assigns the objects to the end of the array during sorting.
    """
    POSITIONAL_MODEL = Role

    @classmethod
    def get_sorting_position(cls, role):
        return (1, 0) if role.is_default else (0, role.position)

    @classmethod
    def get_overwrite_objects(cls, parent_object: DataSheetsCluster):
        return parent_object.roles
```

**managers/**init**.py**

```py
from .record_data import FieldDataManager
from .data_sheets import DataSheetsManager
from .roles import RolesManager
from .positions import (PositionalManager, RolesPositionManager, FieldPositionManager, CategoryPositionManager, DataSheetPositionManager)
```

**models/**init**.py**

```py
from .data_sheets import DataSheet, FieldData, DataSheetField, DataSheetsCluster, DataSheetsCategory
from .roles import Role, RoleOverwrite
```

Both of these directories which I've mentioned are inside a single django app called `api_backend`.
I need these models, however I cannot import them due to django's circular import error.

```py
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\managers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .positions import (PositionalManager, RolesPositionManager, DataSheetFieldPositionManager,
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\managers\positions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from api_backend.models import (Role, DataSheetsCluster, DataSheet, DataSheetField, DataSheetsCategory)
ImportError: cannot import name 'Role' from partially initialized module 'api_backend.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\iyapp\OneDr
ive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\models\__init__.py)
```

Is there a way around this? please help me!
thanks a lot!

Comment: Where are you importing them?

Comment: in both the files mentioned, positions.py and managers.py at the start of the file. is that what you asked?

Comment: I've also add some more details which could help and be important, please see to it! thanks a lot!

Comment: @CosmicReindeer did you ever find a solution?

Comment: yes, please check this post out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548804/django-module-appname-has-no-attribute-models