# django module 'appname' has no attribute 'models'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Everything was working fine until today after I deleted venv and re-created it with pycharm. Now, whatever command I run with django, It throws up this error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'api_backend' has no attribute 'models'
```

full traceback:

```py
(venv) C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger>python manage.py startapp test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_f
rom_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data_sheets import *
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\models\data_sheets.py", line 2, in <module>
    from api_backend.managers.positions import PositionalManager
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\managers\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .field_data import FieldDataManager
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\DataSheet-ledger\api_backend\managers\field_data.py", line 3, in <module>
    import api_backend.models as api_models
AttributeError: module 'api_backend' has no attribute 'models'
```

This is what I did- I deleted the venv, created it again and ran

```py
python -r requirements.txt
```

But then, I cannot do anything else- no migrations or running the server. Why is this so?
Is it because of a circular dependency error?

```py
project structure
```

[image: project structure]

Here are the files mentioned in traceback:
**models/**init**.py**

```py
from .data_sheets import *
from .roles import *
```

**models/datasheets.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from api_backend.managers.positions import PositionalManager
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator


class DataSheetsCluster(models.Model):

    objects = models.Manager()
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)], db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, db_index=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [name]


class DataSheetPositionManager(PositionalManager):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.POSITIONAL_MODEL = DataSheet

    @classmethod
    def get_overwrite_objects(cls, parent_object: DataSheetsCluster):
        return parent_object.datasheets
```

**managers/**init**.py**

```py
from .field_data import FieldDataManager
from .data_sheets import DataSheetsManager
from .roles import RolesManager
from .positions import PositionalManager
```

**managers/field_data.py**

```py
from django.db import models, transaction
import api_backend.models as api_models


class FieldDataManager(models.Manager):
    """
    A manager class to deal with Cluster Size Limits,
    Field DataType Validation and JSON.dumping raw data.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    ...

    def create_field_data(self, field, data: list, owner):
        """
        Creates multiple record data objects with the given
        Serializer data.
        """
        transaction.set_autocommit(False)
        try:
            record_data = [self.create_field_data_object(owner=owner, parent=field, **record) for record in data]
            created_records = api_models.FieldData.objects.bulk_create(record_data)
            field.data.add(*created_records)
        except Exception as err:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise ValueError(err)
        else:
            transaction.commit()
        finally:
            transaction.set_autocommit(True)
        return created_records
```

can someone please help me fix this error? like what models do I need to shift if needed?
thanks for spending your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the circular dependency errors.
I solved this by restructuring my project. So now, managers was a sub-folder inside my models folder. My models can import managers, but managers cannot import models.

To achieve this, I referenced the model from the manager by using

```py
self.model
```

and then, inside the model, I mention the managers like this:

```py
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
    ...
```

So to actually access the manager, I take the model and do

```py
model.objects
```

this way, I dont need to access the managers directly out of the models folder.
Hope this saves someone's time a lot.

what @Jarvis answered was also right, but at an overall view, restructuring my project was a better fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `__init__.py` inside your root directory `api_backend` in order to treat this folder as a package (similar to the ones you have added in your other sub-folders/packages such as `/migrations`, `/models`, `/serializers`, etc.).

Edit: You can do relative import from the `models` folder like this inside your `managers/field_data.py`:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..'))
import models as api_models
```

Comment: Try importing like this then: `from api_backend import models as api_models`

Comment: which file sorry?

Comment: Inside the file you are getting an error: `managers/field_data.py`

Comment: did that it didnt change anything :(

Comment: are you sure it isnt a circular import issue?

Comment: is there any other alternative? because this seems to be anti pattern. Like is my project structure wrong or bad?

Comment: Not an expert about django but it doesn't seem right.